# How to push items of array to another array item by item

Tags: node.js, arrays, typescript, mongodb

I have an array looks like `['N300W150727', '123test123', '123test1234']` I want push it into array mongoDB 
I used `$push` it adds array inside array

```
 async updateSn(updateSn: UpdateSN) {
    const { id, bindedSn } = updateSn;
    return await this.userModel.updateOne(
      { id: id },
      {
        $push: {
          bindedSn: bindedSn,
        },
      },
    );
  }
```

Result

```
bindedSn
:
Array
0
:
"123test123"
1
:
"123test1234"
2
:
Array
```

my questions are : 
1 - How to spread an array inside in mongoDB I used the spread operator nothing happen

```
 async updateSn(updateSn: UpdateSN) {
    const { id, bindedSn } = updateSn;
    return await this.userModel.updateOne(
      { id: id },
      {
        $push: {
          bindedSn: [...bindedSn],
        },
      },
    );
  }
```

2 - How can I send item of the array item by item to the service

Comment: not quite understand, if `$push: { bindedSn }` works? What are you achieve? What is array item by item?

Comment: I want to spread the inner array

Comment: What I understood is you want to push the array into a variable, am I right?

Comment: I want the array in mongodb contain only values not nested arrays , when I $push the array to mongo db it saved as array , but me I want to spread the pushed array I hope u understant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you want to do is to combine **$push** and **$each**

```
userModel.updateOne(
   { id: id },
   { $push: { bindedSn: { $each: bindedSn } } }
)
```

More from docs [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#append-multiple-values-to-an-array)